# Show that we can reorder mixed partials, if every partial is continuous

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, partial-derivative

Suppose $f$ has all partial derivatives up to and including $k$ and all of these partials are continuous. Prove that if $\sigma$ is a permutation on $n$ letters (any reordering), then $$D_{i_1i_2...i_n}f = D_{i{\sigma (1)}i{\sigma (2)}...i{\sigma (n)}}f$$ Basically, prove that we can reorder mixed partials however we like, as long as every partial is continuous.

Comment: duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/765318/showing-the-clairaut-theorem-in-higher-dimensions-partials-commute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each [permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) $\sigma$ can be presented as a concatenation of [transpositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transposition_%28mathematics%29#Transpositions), i.e. you can reach $D_{i{\sigma (1)}i{\sigma (2)}...i{\sigma (n)}}f$ by subsequently change two partial derivatives. You can apply [Schwarz' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives#Schwarz.27_theorem) to prove, that you can change two partial derivatives.